# How do I set tmux to open specified windows at startup?

Tags: shell, tmux

How do I set up tmux so that it starts up with the specified windows opened?

Answer (score 367):

You can write a small shell script that launches tmux with the required programs. I have the following in a shell script that I call dev-tmux. A dev environment:

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-session -d 'vim'
tmux split-window -v 'ipython'
tmux split-window -h
tmux new-window 'mutt'
tmux -2 attach-session -d
```

So everytime I want to launch my favorite dev environment I can just do

```
$ dev-tmux
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to do some horrible escaping to get this to work combined with `bash --rcfile` to get a nice shell on scientific linux with a specific devtools version enabled. Will leave this here if someone tries to do the same. `tmux new-window -n "git lg" "scl enable devtoolset-3 'bash --rcfile <(echo \"source \"$HOME/.bashrc\";cd ~/workspace/coolproject/;git lg\")'"`

Comment: I think the second line must be change, it needs -s option before 'vim'. It means " tmux new-session -d 'vim' " must be replaced by " tmux new-session -d -s 'vim' "

Comment: @AhmadYoosofan, The `vim` there stands for the command that is to be executed in the first (and at that time only) pane of the window. If you instead want to name the session 'vim' then yes, you're right, you got to use the `-s` flag. Whole syntax:

`tmux new-session -d -s SessionName -n WindowName Command`

Comment: watch out: if you have started a tmux session already (elsewhere), the commands could end up in the other session! @waqar-lim 's answer doesn't have this problem.

Comment: So, how do I create the new session named and invoke split-window on that session?

Answer (score 319):

I was trying to create a complex grid of panes and had to deal with switching and splitting panes over and over again. Here are my learnings:

```
tmux new-session \;
```

Gets you started with a new session. To split it horizontal or vertical use `split-window -h` or `-v` subsequently, like that:

```
tmux new-session \; split-window -v \; split-window -h \;
```

Creates 3 panes, like this:

```
------------
|          |
|----------|
|    |     |
------------
```

To run commands in that panes, just add them with the `send-keys 'my-command'` command and `C-m` which executes it:

```
tmux new-session \; \
  send-keys 'tail -f /var/log/monitor.log' C-m \; \
  split-window -v \; \
  split-window -h \; \
  send-keys 'top' C-m \;
```

And the resulting session should look like that.

```
------------
|  tail    |
|----------|
|    | top |
------------
```

Now I tried to again sub-divide the bottom left pane, so switching either back using `last-pane`, or in more complex windows, with the `select-pane -t 1` where `1` is the number of the pane in order created starting with `0`.

```
tmux new-session \; \
  send-keys 'tail -f /var/log/monitor.log' C-m \; \
  split-window -v \; \
  split-window -h \; \
  send-keys 'top' C-m \; \
  select-pane -t 1 \; \
  split-window -v \; \
  send-keys 'weechat' C-m \;
```

Does that. Basicaly knowing your way around with `split-window` and `select-pane` is all you need. It's also handy to pass with `-p 75` a percentage size of the pane created by `split-window` to have more control over the size of the panes.

```
tmux new-session \; \
  send-keys 'tail -f /var/log/monitor.log' C-m \; \
  split-window -v -p 75 \; \
  split-window -h -p 30 \; \
  send-keys 'top' C-m \; \
  select-pane -t 1 \; \
  split-window -v \; \
  send-keys 'weechat' C-m \;
```

Which results in a session looking like that

```
------------------
|      tail      |
|----------------|
|          | top |
|----------|     |
| weechat  |     |
------------------
```

Comment: amazing guideline, could you guide me how to resize the width of the vertical panel after split.

Comment: @MinhNV `-h -p 30` creates a horizontal panel with 30% of the available height; `-v -p 75` same for vertical with 75% width.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `\:`? I've seen scripts work with and without this.

Comment: UPDATE: `\;` passes the semicolon to tmux instead of bash, allowing the commands to be sent with one call to tmux. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913198/why-are-the-backslash-and-semicolon-required-with-the-find-commands-exec-optio

Comment: `tmux new-session \; split-window -v -p 50 \; split-window -h -p 50 \; select-pane -t 0 \; split-window -h -p 50 \;` to create a pane devided into 4 panes equally spaced

Comment: Hello, thanks for your amazing reply, what if I would like to put the mouse on and change the prefix throught the `ctrl+b : set-options -g prefix M-w` command for that session? thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your amazing answer. From this answer I got what I wanted: open several windows as if I did it with C-b c, run a program in each one of them and when the program ends go back to bash (doesn't close the window). I've added sleep so they open in the order I want. I add the script as another answer in case anyone is interested.

Answer (score 113):

You can source different sessions from your `.tmux.conf` like so:

```
# initialize sessions
bind S source-file ~/.tmux/session1 
bind s source-file ~/.tmux/session2
```

And then format the sessions as you require:

```
#session1
new  -s SessionName -n WindowName Command
neww -n foo/bar foo
splitw -v -p 50 -t 0 bar
selectw -t 1 
selectp -t 0
```

This would open 2 windows, the second of which would be named foo/bar and would be split vertically in half (50%) with foo running above bar. Focus would be in window 2 (foo/bar), top pane (foo).

You can then start your preferred tmux session (in this case, session1) with <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>

Comment: Can't those session be started inside .tmux.conf without requiring extra files?

Comment: One of them could: this way you can easily add more tailored sessions - and a couple of tiny text files is hardly an overhead...

Comment: Wouldn't this be session nesting? I mean to run `Prefix Shift S` I need to be in tmux and sourcing your file tries to start a new session which tmux doesn't like and won't do unless you force it to.

Comment: @user35915 it will simply not start a child session, but a separate one - on that you can switch to using e.g. prefix-s or prefix-) and prefix-(

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. However binding to s (not S) will override the built-in tmux binding for listing sessions.

Comment: and how to load a (default) session without pressing any key? just at tmux startup (as in the op's question) and without a sub-file (without having to use `source-file` command)?

Answer (score 63):

Use [tmuxinator](https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator) - it allows you to have multiple sessions configured, and you can choose which one to launch at any given time. You can launch commands in particular windows or panes and give titles to windows. Here is an [example use with developing Django applications](http://andrewbrookins.com/tech/instant-django-dev-environments-with-tmux-tmuxinator-and-virtualenvwrapper/).

Sample config file:

```
# ~/.tmuxinator/project_name.yml
# you can make as many tabs as you wish...

project_name: Tmuxinator
project_root: ~/code/rails_project
socket_name: foo # Not needed. Remove to use default socket
rvm: 1.9.2@rails_project
pre: sudo /etc/rc.d/mysqld start
tabs:
  - editor:
      layout: main-vertical
      panes:
        - vim
        - #empty, will just run plain bash
        - top
  - shell: git pull
  - database: rails db
  - server: rails s
  - logs: tail -f logs/development.log
  - console: rails c
  - capistrano:
  - server: ssh me@myhost
```

See the README at the above link for a full explanation.

Comment: tmuxinator is basically exactly what I was looking for. thanks!

Comment: there's also tmuxp which is fairly similar: https://github.com/tony/tmuxp

Comment: This answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472256/259701) has a command to dump the current tmux layout which can then be used in tmuxinator:

`tmux list-windows -F "#{window_active} #{window_layout}" | grep "^1" | cut -d " " -f 2`

Answer (score 22):

```
:~$ tmux new-session "tmux source-file ~/session1"
```

## session1

```
neww
split-window -v 'ipython'  
split-window -h  
new-window 'mutt'
```

### create an alias in .bashrc

```
:~$ echo `alias tmux_s1='tmux new-session "tmux source-file ~/session1"'` >>~/.bashrc  
:~$ . ~/.bashrc  
:~$ tmux_s1
```

Comment: ~What's `neww`? I can't find that command anywhere.~ It looks like it is `new-window`, although I can't understand why you use both the long and short form.

Answer (score 17):

have  a look @ https://github.com/remiprev/teamocil

you can specify your structure using YAML

```
windows:
  - name: sample-window
    splits:
      - cmd: vim
      - cmd:
        - ipython
        width: 50
      - cmd:
        height: 25
```

Answer (score 15):

This script starts a session with the name "e" and three windows

```
#!/bin/sh 
tmux new-session -s e   -n etc -d 'cd /etc; bash -i'
tmux new-window  -t e:1 -n home   'cd ~; bash -i'
tmux new-window  -t e:2 -n log   'cd /var/log; bash -i'

tmux select-window -t e:1
tmux -2 attach-session -t e
```

Answer (score 13):

From my "get.all" script, which I invoke each morning to run a bunch of subsequent "get.XXX" jobs to refresh the software that I track.  Some of them are auto-quitting. Others require more interaction once the get has finished (like asking to build emacs).

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux att -t get ||
tmux \
  new -s get -n capp \; \
  send-keys 'get.capp' C-m \; \
  neww -n emacs \; \
  send-keys 'get.emacs' C-m \; \
  neww -n git \; \
  send-keys 'get.git' C-m \; \
  neww -n mini \; \
  send-keys 'get.mini' C-m \; \
  neww -n port \; \
  send-keys 'get.port' C-m \; \
  neww -n rakudo \; \
  send-keys 'get.rakudo' C-m \; \
  neww -n neil \; \
  send-keys 'get.neil && get.neil2 && exit' C-m \; \
  neww -n red \; \
  send-keys 'get.red && exit' C-m \; \
  neww -n cpan \; \
  send-keys 'get.cpan && exit' C-m \; \
  selectw -t emacs
```

Comment: somewhat unrelated, but you might want to have a look at https://github.com/r-darwish/topgrade ;)

Answer (score 12):

If you just want to split screen on 2 panes (say horizontally), you can run this command (no tmux or shell scripts required):

```
tmux new-session \; split-window -h \;
```

You screen will look like this:

```
[ks@localhost ~]$                      │[ks@localhost ~]$ 
                                       │
                                       │
                                       │
                                       │
                                       │
                                       │
                                       │
                                       │
                                       │
                                       │
                                       │
[10] 0:ks@localhost:~*                  "localhost.localdomain" 19:51 31-янв-16
```

Answer (score 11):

First i had the approach from [@jasonwryan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753059/1592039) but if you have more then 2 configs, it can get confusing.

So i created an alias function:

```
tmx () {
    tmux "$2" source-file "$HOME/.tmux/$1.conf";
}
```

In `~/.tmux/` i have multiple sessions for many uses. For example i work for different companies that have each another dev environment. So with the alias function above i can simply call: `tmx company1` and load the config i need.

**Update:** The purpose of "$2" after the `tmux` command is, that you are able to pass additional tmux args.

Comment: Combining this with the tips from @soc1c made a super-sweet setup (https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/commit/35a7ed). Thanks!

Comment: The function doesn't actually work when there isn't already an existing tmux session to hook onto (get `no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default`). That's why I needed to patch the command with `tmux new-session`. Ref https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/commit/43d481956c73826cc9cfe1d971e91e2ae3c3dfe9#diff-64848524db7ba4dea710a785457b57ecR189

Comment: I did my tmux setup with systemd. So there is always a session running after boot. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Autostart_with_systemd Sorry for not mention it.

Answer (score 9):

And this is how I do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

function has-session {
  tmux has-session -t name_of_my_session 2>/dev/null
}

if has-session ; then
  echo "Session already exists"
else
  cd /path/to/my/project
  tmux new-session -d -s name_of_my_session 'vim'
  tmux split-window -h -p 40 start_web_server
  tmux split-window -v
  tmux attach-session -d -t name_of_my_session
fi
```

I have one file for each of my project. Also you can group them to have some for work some for hobby projects.

Also you can move it to `~/bin` folder, add it to `PATH` and give `tmux_my_awesome_project` name. Then you will be able to run it from each place.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [tmux hooks](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#HOOKS) to execute commands when a new session is created. Specifically, this is achieved using the `session-created` hook.

For example, to split the screen three ways with top running in the lower right you can add the following line to your `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
set-hook -g session-created 'split -h ; split -v top'
```

The advantage of this method is that you don't have to run tmux in any special way (i.e., shell script or alias) to get the desired result. You can also combine this with `tmux new-session -A -s mysession` described in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49134974/1352437) such that the hook commands are only run when you first create the session and not on subsequent attachments.

This feature was added by [d15d54c2c](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/d15d54c2c8e6b95695169442eb2a27d814efc078) back in 2016. The first release to include it is is 2.4.

Answer (score 6):

Try [bro](https://github.com/ludbek/bro), it is a project bootstrapper.

It provides easy apis to interact with `tmux`.

It looks something like this :

```
#!/bin/sh
# @ project_name/tasks/init.sh
structure project_name
  window editor
    run 'vim'
  window terminal
    run 'echo happy coding ...'
focus editor
connect project_name
```

To launch a project all one needs to do is run following command -

`bro start <project_name>`

Checkout the screencast below, it shows how to get started with `bro` and use its `tmux` api.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8296449/50532502-2cf3e400-0b6e-11e9-84af-c5f77a04e5cc.gif

Answer (score 5):

There is a tmux plugin for this.

Check out [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect)

> Restore tmux environment after system restart.
>
> Tmux is great, except when you have to restart the computer. You lose all the running programs, working directories, pane layouts etc. There are helpful management tools out there, but they require initial configuration and continuous updates as your workflow evolves or you start new projects.
>
> tmux-resurrect saves all the little details from your tmux environment so it can be completely restored after a system restart (or when you feel like it). No configuration is required. You should feel like you never quit tmux.

Or [tmux-continuum](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum)

> Features:
>
> - continuous saving of tmux environment
> - automatic tmux start when computer/server is turned on
> - automatic restore when tmux is started

Answer (score 4):

This works for me. Creating 5 windows with the given names and auto selecting to the `home` window.

```
new  -n home
neww -n emacs
neww -n puppet
neww -n haskell
neww -n ruby
selectw -t 1
```

Answer (score 4):

[`smux.py`](https://pypi.org/project/smux.py/) allows you to simply list the commands you want in each pane, prefixed with a line containing three dashes.

Here's an example smux file that starts three panes.

```
---
echo "This is pane 1."
---
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/hq6/smux
cd smux
less smux.py
---
man tmux
```

If you put this in a file called `Sample.smux`, you can then run the following to launch.

```
pip3 install smux.py
smux.py Sample.smux
```

Full disclaimer: I am the author of smux.py.

Answer (score 3):

To simply open tmux with multiple panes and run some commands, I created the following bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux split-window -v -p 30 -c ~/path/to/folder1
tmux split-window -h -p 66 -c ~/path/to/folder2
tmux split-window -h -p 50 'mongod'
```

Run the bash file to get the following:

```
-----------------------------------
|                                 |
|---------------------------------|
|  folder1  | folder2  |  mongod  |
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: I get error connecting to /private/tmp/tmux-501/default (No such file or directory) when runnning it on macosx

Comment: You have to save it as a .sh file. So for example: default.sh and then run it by typing the path to that file in full. For example `/private/tmp/tmux-501/default.sh`

Answer (score 2):

[tmuxp](http://tmuxp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/about.html) support JSON or YAML session configuration and a python API. A simple tmuxp configuration file to create a new session in YAML syntax is:

```
session_name: 2-pane-vertical
windows:
  - window_name: my test window
    panes:
      - pwd
      - pwd
```

Answer (score 2):

The plugin [tmux-continuum](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum) will auto save your tmux session and load it the next time tmux starts, should be easier to setup than some of the custom script solutions here.

> Features:
>
> - continuous saving of tmux environment
> - automatic tmux start when computer/server is turned on
> - automatic restore when tmux is started

To save your session on demand you can use the [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) plugin. [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) is also required to run [tmux-continuum](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum)

> tmux-resurrect saves all the little details from your tmux environment
>   so it can be completely restored after a system restart (or when you
>   feel like it). No configuration is required. You should feel like you
>   never quit tmux.

Answer (score 2):

I know my solution is quite similar to others, but I couldn't find any that had exactly what I was looking for :

- I want to open titled windows at specific paths
- I want to have as many windows and panes as I want
- I want to run arbitrary commands in each of the panes, persisted in history
- I want to focus the window I want at the end of the script
- I want being able to spawn this very quickly
- I want it to be easy to maintain

For my project named `johndoe`, I create a `johndoe.conf` file which is essentially a bash script, somewhere in my configs (`~/.config/tmux/tmux-sessions/johndoe.conf`).

This file is simple to maintain because it does not have a myriad of `\` everywhere like I saw in other answers:

```
# Create a new session named johndoe, with a first window named Main 
# at the specified starting path.
# The -d is for detached mode, which allows me to continue defining the rest of the session 
# before attaching to it. Without -d, tmux would open the client right away and
# ignore the rest of the session definition
tmux new -d -s johndoe -n 'Main' -c ~/dev/own/johndoe
# Simulate the user entering some docker command in the first window available 
# in the target session named (-t) johndoe
tmux send -t johndoe 'docker compose up -d' Enter

# Create a new window in the target session, with the title 'UI run'
tmux neww -t pers -n 'UI run' -c ~/dev/own/johndoe/front-end
# Simulate user entering a command to the first pane
tmux send -t pers:'UI run.0' 'git status --short' Enter 
# Split this window horizontally
tmux split-window -t pers:'UI run' -h -c ~/dev/own/johndoe/front-end
# Simulate user entering a command to the second pane in this window
tmux send -t pers:'UI run.1' 'npm run dev' Enter 

tmux neww -t johndoe -n 'API run' -c ~/dev/own/johndoe/back-end/Api
tmux send -t johndoe:'API run' 'dotnet run --no-build' Enter

# Focus the first window
tmux select-window -t johndoe:'Main'
# Attach the current terminal to the only session available 
# (you might want to add "-t johndoe" here if you need several sessions running in parallel)
tmux a -d
```

2. I create a bash/zsh alias to source this session configuration :

```
alias tmuxjohndoe='. ~/.config/tmux/tmux-sessions/johndoe.conf'
```

3. I spend just the right amount of debugging time figuring out that I need to give execution permissions to the `johndoe.conf` file :-)
4. Now from anywhere, I just run `tmuxjohndoe` !

Answer (score 1):

I've create [this script](https://github.com/sensorario/startmux). It does not need tmuxinator, ruby or others. It is just a bash script, configurable:

A file named config should contains something like this:

```
combo=()
combo+=('logs' 'cd /var/log; clear; pwd')
combo+=('home' 'cd ~; clear; pwd')
```

and the bash code should be:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -r config ]; then
    echo ""
    echo "Loading custom file"
    . config
else
    . config.dist
fi

tmux start-server

window=0
windownumber=-1

for i in "${combo[@]}"; do

    if [ $((window%2)) == 0 ]; then
        name=${i}
        ((windownumber++))
    else
        command=${i}
    fi

    if [ ${combo[0]} == "${i}" ]; then
        tmux new-session -d -s StarTmux -n "${name}"
    else
        if [ $((window%2)) == 0 ]; then
            tmux new-window -tStarTmux:$windownumber -n "${name}"
        fi
    fi

    if [ $((window%2)) == 1 ]; then
        tmux send-keys -tStarTmux:$windownumber "${command}" C-m
    fi

    ((window++))
done

tmux select-window -tStarTmux:0
tmux attach-session -d -tStarTmux
```

Comment: Hi sensorario, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: N.b. amazingly, `tmux start_server` doesn't start a server on its own. See https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/182

Answer (score 1):

I just tried using all the ideas on this page and I didn't like any of them.  I just wanted a solution that started tmux with a specific set of windows when my terminal opened.  I also wanted it to be idempotent, i.e. opening a new terminal window takes over the tmux session from the previous one.

The above solutions often tend to open multiple tmux sessions and I want just one.  First, I added this to my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
tmux start-server
if [[ -z "$TMUX" ]]
then
  exec tmux attach -d -t default
fi
```

then I added the following to my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
new -s default -n emacs /usr/local/bin/emacs
neww -n shell /usr/local/bin/bash
neww -n shell /usr/local/bin/bash
selectw -t 1
```

now every time I start a terminal or start tmux or whatever, I either reattach to my existing desired setup (the session named `default`), or create a new session with that setup.

Comment: amazingly, `tmux start_server` doesn't start a server on its own. See https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/182

Answer (score 0):

You should specify it in your tmux config file (`~/.tmux.conf`), for example:

```
new mocp
neww mutt

new -d
neww
neww
```

(opens one session with 2 windows with mocp launched in first and mutt in second, and another detached session with 3 empty windows).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a new TMUX session named "my_session" with a single window
tmux new-session -d -s my_session -n my_window

# Split the window horizontally into two panes
tmux split-window -h

# Split the second pane vertically into two additional panes
tmux select-pane -t 1
tmux split-window -v

# Rename the panes for easier identification
tmux select-pane -t 0
tmux rename-pane "Main"
tmux select-pane -t 1
tmux rename-pane "Left"
tmux select-pane -t 2
tmux rename-pane "Right Top"
tmux select-pane -t 3
tmux rename-pane "Right Bottom"

# Attach to the new session with the desired pane configuration
tmux attach-session -t my_session
```

Answer (score 0):

From [q9f](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1260906/q9f)'s answer edited by [starball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/starball) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40009032/3414196 I have done some tests to get what I wanted: Create the windows as if I did it by hand with C-b c and after closing the programs, go back to bash (do not close the window). From [Randal Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz)'s answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6589715/3414196 I have done some tests to go to first window.

```
#!/bin/sh

# tmux new-session \; \
#  send-keys 'tail -f /var/log/monitor.log' C-m \; \
#  split-window -v -p 75 \; \
#  split-window -h -p 30 \; \
#  send-keys 'top' C-m \; \
#  select-pane -t 1 \; \
#  split-window -v \; \
#  send-keys 'weechat' C-m \;

tmux new-session -n top \; \
  send-keys 'top' C-m \; \
  new-window -n firefox \; \
  send-keys 'firefox' C-m \; \
  new-window -n 'weechat' \; \
  send-keys 'sleep 2s ; weechat' C-m \; \
  selectw -t 0
```