# tmux start new pane with my current environemnt

Tags: android, build, tmux

I am doing an Android build and it needs to source the build environment. If I create a new tmux pane, how can I carry over all my environment variables without sourcing the buildenv again?

Comment: Something like that is not terribly straightforward. Is it really so onerous to reestablish your buildenv? Here are some hints: 1) The only commands that use any of the client’s environment (besides when initially starting a server) are `new-session` and `attach-session`. 2) Those commands only update the resulting environment with the variables named in the `update-environment` option. 3) You can use `join-pane` to split a window/pane and pull in an existing pane (even from some other (e.g. temporary) session).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Chris. I can potentially put the source build/envsetup.sh and lunch combo (for Android) inside my bashrc itself, but it would probably slow it down. `update-environment` doesn't work since there are also functions sourced. I will look into the `join-pane` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tmuxinator](https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator) might fit your needs, please refer to [How to set up tmux so that it starts up with specified windows opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609192/how-to-set-up-tmux-so-that-it-starts-up-with-specified-windows-opened)

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Well, I wanted a way to do it without predefining my sessions, but I guess this will have to do! Thanks!