# How to attach screen seesion or create it?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I am currently using this to launch `mutt` or `irssi`:

```
urxvt -name Irssi/Mutt screen -r Irssi/Mutt
```

Currently I have to do the following before using my launcher:

```
screen -S Irssi/Mutt irssi/mutt + Ctrl-a-d
```

What I am looking to do is:

```
if [ test_to_see_if_the_screen_exit ]  # I need a way to the test
then
  urxvt -name Irssi/Mutt -e screen -r Irssi/Mutt
else
  create_the_screen_named_Irssi/Mutt_and_detach_it # I need a way to create it
  urxvt -name Irssi/Mutt -e screen -r Irssi/Mutt
endif
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: well it's not an answer, rather suggestion, TMUX is much better than screen. I have used both screen and TMUX, and TMUX is much more user friendly and with many more flexibility

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: I have tmux, and in .bashrc, `alias t='tmux attach || tmux new'` this helps to either attach to an existing session, or create a new one. in a tmux session, you can have multiple windows each running separate program. So just replace `tmux new` with what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609192/how-to-set-up-tmux-so-that-it-starts-up-with-specified-windows-opened this link will show you how to do that

Comment: That is pretty cool, I will surely try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `screen -list` or `screen -ls` to show your existing screens.

I would probably do your `if...endif` bit this way, though:

```
screen_opts=""
case $(screen -list Irssi/Mutt | awk '/Irssi/{print $NF}') in
  *Attached*) ;; # not sure what you would want here,
                 # but I would probably do 'screen_opts="-x"'...
  *Detached*) screen_opts="-r" ;;
  *) screen -wipe # if session is dead, clean it up
     screen_opts="-S Irssi/Mutt";;
esac
urxvt -name Irssi/Mutt -e screen ${screen_opts}
```

Comment: You have to use the -e option for urxvt to launch the command. Thanks

Comment: @JacobIlyane You're right... I just copy-pastad the OP's command... Fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `screen -list | grep Irssi/Mutt` to see if your session already exists.

But it's easier to just let `screen` figure out if the session exists:

```
screen -r Irssi/Mutt || screen -S Irssi/Mutt irssi/mutt
```

This will try to attach to an existing session, and create a new one if attaching fails (and you don't need to detach and reattach right away, just stay in the session).

To make `urxvt` run that, you'll have to specify `sh` explicitly:

```
urxvt -name Irssi/Mutt -e sh -c 'screen -r Irssi/Mutt || screen -S Irssi/Mutt irssi/mutt'
```