# tmux: How to automatically open sessions, windows, and panes

Tags: tmux

I'm new to tmux and would like to configure it such that when I run `tmux`, my customized windows/panes are immediately accessible.

For example, here's a basic ~/.tmux.conf:

```
new -s main -n workspace
neww
```

When I run tmux, I get dumped into a plain old session. When I do a `list-sessions`, I can see the workspace session specified in the conf file, but in order to use it, I have to switch to it.

How can I just go ahead and make the "workspace" session the session I'm dumped into when I open tmux so that I don't have to switch to it every time?

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609192/how-to-set-up-tmux-so-that-it-starts-up-with-specified-windows-opened/5753059#5753059)

Comment: I saw it; however, it doesn't answer my question because to activate your session, I have to bind it to a key. I want mine to automatically open and drop me into my custom session.

Comment: How about this [approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40125397/1592039)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understood the question, but I use [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) to quickly launch sessions pre-populated with windows, panes and processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach to the last used session (which will be the one your conf file created if applicable) by running `tmux attach` instead of just `tmux`.

If you have more than one session setup in your config, you can choose which one you land on by using the session name target flag like: `tmux attach -t <session_name>`.

Answer (score 1):

I've create [this script](https://github.com/sensorario/startmux). It does not need tmuxinator, ruby or others. It is just a bash script, configurable:

A file named config should contains something like this:

```
combo=()
combo+=('logs' 'cd /var/log; clear; pwd')
combo+=('home' 'cd ~; clear; pwd')
```

and the bash code should be:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -r config ]; then
    echo ""
    echo "Loading custom file"
    . config
else
    . config.dist
fi

tmux start-server

window=0
windownumber=-1

for i in "${combo[@]}"; do

    if [ $((window%2)) == 0 ]; then
        name=${i}
        ((windownumber++))
    else
        command=${i}
    fi

    if [ ${combo[0]} == "${i}" ]; then
        tmux new-session -d -s StarTmux -n "${name}"
    else
        if [ $((window%2)) == 0 ]; then
            tmux new-window -tStarTmux:$windownumber -n "${name}"
        fi
    fi

    if [ $((window%2)) == 1 ]; then
        tmux send-keys -tStarTmux:$windownumber "${command}" C-m
    fi

    ((window++))
done

tmux select-window -tStarTmux:0
tmux attach-session -d -tStarTmux
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a session in your `.tmux.conf` file, but you never attach to it. When you just run

```
tmux
```

there is no command specified, so it defaults to running `new-session` and attaching to the resulting session.

It's a little cleaner to limit your `.tmux.conf` file to various settings, and reserve session creation and management to a separate script.

```
#!/bin/bash

tmux new -s main -n workspace
tmux neww  # Creates a 2nd window, in addition to the new session's first window
tmux attach -t main
```

Comment: I like this, but is it a best practice? I only ask because [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609192/how-to-set-up-tmux-so-that-it-starts-up-with-specified-windows-opened/5753059#comment6585934_5752901) on a related question shows a differing opinion.

Comment: Actually, everything works if I just, like you said, attach to the session when I start tmux ala `tmux attach-session main`. And I could add an alias to my .bash_profile to shorten that down to an alias.

Comment: `tmux a` will launch and attach to the default session, ie., the one specified in your `.tmux.conf` @doremi

Answer (score 0):

Use my script. [IniTmux](https://github.com/iasj/IniTmux). You can easyly describe you sessions, windows and panes with simple YAML files.

```
---
name: AK-Math 
root: /i/project/LibAK/feature/Math
windows:
- Matrix  : feature
- Vector  : feature
- Number  : feature
- Complex : feature
- Real    : feature
- Integer : feature
- Bool    : feature

- Math:
    layout : tiled
    dir    : branch
    panes  :
    - 'ranger'
    - ''

models:
    feature:
        layout: "40fd,113x31,0,0[113x22,0,0{22x22,0,0,0,90x22,23,0,1},113x9,0,23,2]"
        dir: <WName>
        panes:
        - loop "tree obj" 0.5
        - vim -c VWSLoadWorkSpace
        - ''
```