# tmux: programatically split a window horizontally and run two commands?

Tags: linux, macos, tmux

**(dupe note)** This is not a dupe of [How to set up tmux so that it starts up with specified windows opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609192/how-to-set-up-tmux-so-that-it-starts-up-with-specified-windows-opened).  That question revolves around configuring tmux, and none of the answers there provide an answer to this question. **(end note)**

Suppose I have two commands

```
tail -f log1
tail -f log2
```

How can I programatically call tmux to split a window horizontally and run each of the commands in its own pane, something similar to:

```
for i in log1 log2; do xterm -e tail -f $i& done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up tmux so that it starts up with specified windows opened?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609192/how-to-set-up-tmux-so-that-it-starts-up-with-specified-windows-opened)

Comment: Not a dupe. I'm not interested in configuring tmux startup, just how to split the current window as described and run the commands.  None of the questions answer that.

Comment: Note that I'm looking for a single call that will do this.  Your comment involves manually typing two commands.

Comment: **What** do you want? I gave you a link to a single command, and explained commands which can be manually typed when inside a session. Both of them fit your use case.

Comment: I think I'm a bit dumb... I'm not seeing the single command you're linking to.  Try providing the answer as an answer, see how I updated to show the xterm example. It would be most appreciated, as my dumbness is preventing me from understanding what you're saying.

Comment: Oh, and keep in mind that I would like to do this programatically.  If I were simply asking how to use tmux to split a screen, it would be better asked on one of the other SO sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no single command to accomplish this; rather, you send multiple commands to the server. This can be done, though, via a single invocation of `tmux`.

```
tmux new-session -d tail -f log1 \; split-window tail -f log2 \; attach
```

Note that an escaped semicolon is used to separate `tmux` commands. Unescaped semicolons are treated as part of the shell command executed by a particular `tmux` command.

Adapting the loop in your question might look something like:

```
tmux_command="new-session -d"
commands=("tail -f log1" "tail -f log2" "tail -f log3")
tmux_command+=" ${commands[0]}"
for cmd in "${commands[@]:1}"; do
    tmux_command+="\; split-window $cmd"
done
tmux "$tmux_command \; attach"
```

Comment: perfect, thanks.  I fixed the first example, removing the outside set of single quotes.