# Why does my shell script for creating a split-window tmux session not work

Tags: shell, zsh, tmux

I am on macOS and using zsh.
I have created a folder `~/bin/` which I've added to my path. I created a shell script `~/bin/testscript` containing the following code

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-session -s testsession
tmux split-window -v
```

and used `chmod -R 700 ~/bin` to set the permissions `-rwx------`.

When executing the lines from the shell script successively by typing them in the shell I get a new tmux session with vertically split windows. This is the expected behavior. However, when I type `testscript` into the shell I only get a new tmux session, but without vertically split windows.

What do I need to do to change in the script to get a session with split windows? I've copied the above code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609192/how-to-set-up-tmux-so-that-it-starts-up-with-specified-windows-opened), but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you type `test` in the shell and your script actually runs at all, then there is something you're not telling us.  `test` should be a shell builtin.  What mechanism are you using to avoid that?

Comment: I didn't tell you that my script is actually named 'testscript' instead of 'test'. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a new session, *and* you immediately attach to that session. This causes the first call to `tmux` to block until you detach from that session, preventing the script from preceding to the second call to `tmux`.

To prevent that, create the new session without attaching to it immediately by using the `-d` option. Once you've used `split-window` to create the second pane, *then* you can attach to the session.

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-session -d -s testsession
tmux split-window -v -t testsession
tmux attach -t testsession
```

`split-window`'s `-t` option technically takes a window, not a session, but as the new session only has one window, it defaults to that window.

`tmux attach`, with no `-t` option, will attach to the most recently used session, so `-t testsession` can be considered optional here.

Comment: 'This causes the first call to 'tmux' to block.' I think my mental model is wrong. Isn't the first call to tmux 'tmux new-session -s testsession' already fully executed once the new session is created, and I immediately attached to it? In my imagination that would mean that the second line, 'tmux split-window -v' is then executed _within_ the new tmux session exactly _because_ I've immediately attached to it.

Comment: `tmux` is heavily overloaded; it's an executable that could create a `tmux` session or server or client, depending on its arguments. In the case of `new-session`, it creates a new session, then starts a client *attached* to that session; the process itself doesn't exit until the client detaches from the session. With `-d`, no new client is created; only a new session, allowing the `tmux` process to exit immediately after creating the session. `tmux attach` simply creates a new client that attaches to a pre-existing session.

Answer (score 2):

When you run those command manually, you are typing the 2nd line in a shell running in the new session.  When you run the script, the 2nd line is not executing inside that session.  Try:

```
tmux new-session -s testsession "$SHELL" \; split-window -v
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

tmux new-session -d -s testsession
tmux split-window -v -t testsession:0.0
tmux attach-session -t testsession
```

Comment: You also need the `-d` option to `new-session`, to prevent attaching to the new session immediately.

Comment: I tried just now. This doesn't work either.

Comment: @user9007131 No, that didn't work.  Edited to a working solution.

Comment: With '-d', and removing the ':0.0', it does work. What's wrong about attaching immediately though? I've added an additional line 'tmux a -t testsession' at the end for now.

Comment: @user9007131 If you attach immediately, the split-window command doesn't run until after you detach from the session.

Comment: `-d` *isn't* necessary if you include all the `tmux` commands in single call :) (Making the final `attach` command also unnecessary.)

Comment: You should probably remove the ':0.0' so I can accept your answer, because it only worked after I did remove that.

Comment: `0.0` should have worked; it's just explicitly specifying the first (and only) pane in the first (and only) window in `testsession`. (Unless you are using `base-index` and/or `pane-base-index` to start numbering them with something other than 0.)

Comment: @chepner Well it does not though. "can't find window: 0"

Comment: @user9007131 Hmm.  It works for me.  What version of tmux are you using?