# Create a session in the background if it doesn't exist but do not attach in tmux

Tags: shell, tmux

I've looked at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432536/create-session-if-none-exists) which asks about creating a `tmux` session, or attaching if it doesn't exist.

What I'd like to do is a little different: create a `tmux` session if it doesn't exist, but don't attach. The plan is to create a few different sessions with canonical names, then send commands to them using `tmux send`. Is there an easy way in `tmux` or shell scripting to create a session with a specific name only if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you try to create a session with the same name tmux returns an error with exit code 1.

```
drizzt@liara ~ % tmux new-session -d -s test 
drizzt@liara ~ % tmux new-session -d -s test
duplicate session: test
drizzt@liara ~ % echo $?
1
drizzt@liara ~ %
```

If you don't like the duplicate session error you can do something like:

```
drizzt@liara ~ % tmux has-session -t test || tmux new-session -d -s test
```